# When and how are packages added to TeX Live?

Tags: texlive, ctan

I've noticed that some of the packages I've uploaded to CTAN are now in TL2011, and some I've updated lately have been updated in TL2011, too.

When are packages added/updated in TeX Live? Is it an automated process, or a manual one? What can be done to ease it?

Comment: AFAIK it is a semi-automatic process. At least new packages need some manual interaction I think. Then the TeX Live project uses some scripts to detect updates of this packages. I think one way to ease things is to also provide a TDS ZIP file of your packages.

Comment: @Martin: thanks for fixing my typos ;-)

Comment: @Martin: what are these TDS ZIP ?

Comment: http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=tds-zip

Comment: I would like to note that providing TDS packages is not necessary if you have a properly written `.ins` file.

Comment: @Andrey: Yes, but it simplifies things. AFAIK MikTeX prefers them and they also allow for easy manual installation if someone has to run an older TL version. @Rhaphink: There is also the `ctanify` tool which will create both ZIP files for you.

Comment: Thanks @Martin. I'll have a look at `ctanify`. So basically I can use `sty2dtx` first to create the dtx, and then `ctanify`  to create the tds.zip ?

Comment: @Andrey: if I commit a tds.zip, does that mean I don't commit the ins?

Comment: @Raphink: No, you would transmit everything. `ctanify` makes a TDS ZIP file and then puts this together with the DTX, INS and PDF into a new compressed file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Suitable packages are taken from CTAN and is manually packaged for TL. Note that the process may take a few days because most people get their data from mirrors, so the meirrors need to update themselfs with the new data.

To ease the process: Release under the LPPL, remember to include the source code for the manual. Then there is nothing to it.

If a package was updated on ctan, but not on TL (some days later), then send an email to the texlive list (see tug.org)

Comment: Thanks @daleif. I do provide dtx+ins+pdf in my packages and release them under the LPPL.

Comment: note "release under the lppl" includes documenting that fact in the package; simply selecting lppl on the upload form isn't enough (for example, the linux distros sometimes check licences, and by that time the upload form is long gone.